# mqtt kafka bridge install - 'annotations are not supported in source 1.3' error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install MQTT KAFKA on Ubuntu and getting an 'annotations are not supported in source 1.3' error when we run ANT cmd.

From researching the issue we see that a few fixes are out there but they have not solved our issue:

- Set Java_Home dir to correct version
- edit pom.xml java version 1.7

I suspect it is something to do with the java setup as i have seen other install issues but i cant be certain due to my limited prowess on Linux systems.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of items with this:

1. a dependency called Paho Java MQTT Client is needed. This can be manually installed from the Paho site, use version 0.4.0. Run mvn clean install to add it to your local maven repo and then edit the pom.xml that comes with mqttKafkaBridge to point at the jar and pom files which were added to your local maven repo. there seems to be an error in the pom.xml which comes qith mqttKafkaBridge as it references Paho 0.9.0, which doesnt exist and changing it to 0.4.0 doesnt resolve it.Make sure you run mvn clean install in the top level folder, not in any of the subfolders. Also watch out for a compile issue with the ClientComms.java file. To fix this, edit the build.xml file under the org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3 folder to point it to the correct location for ClientComms.java, i.e.: /src/main/java-templates/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/internal/ClientComms.java
2. kafka 0.7.2 is also required. it wont work with 0.8.0-beta1 (i tested both). to get 0.7.2, download the source and install using sbt (simple build tool) see: http://kafka.apache.org/07/quickstart.html. Unfortunately this doesnt add kafka 0.7.2 to your local maven repo. To do this go in to the kafka source directory and run: mvn install:install-file -Dfile=core/target/scala_2.8.0/kafka-0.7.2.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.kafka -DartifactId=kafka -Dversion=0.7.2 -Dpackaging=jar. Then you need to go back to the mqttKafkaBridge and edit the kafka dependency in the pom.xml file to point to this. Running ./sbt publish-local && ./sbt publish for kafka 0.8.0-beta1 will work and add it to your local maven repo (.m2/repository) but the mqttKafkaBridge compile will fail stating that the kafka 0.8.0-beta1 is not valid. Running ./sbt publish-local works for kafka 0.7.2 but ./sbt publish fails so you need to use the mvn install:install-file route (which doesnt work for 0.8.0-beta1).
3. last step was also tough. Found a link on this which helped resolve it for me: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-dev/201301.mbox/%3CJIRA.12523213.1316101732625.79420.1357290855035@arcas%3E. The article suggests that ANT wont work for compiling it and to use maven. run mvn clean install instead of ANT and it should compile for you.

there is not much documentation out there on this and the components and versions are all fairly recently developed so hopefully this post will help others with the issue.